# Proving a piece-wise function is continuous at a point

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I have the function:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}  \ \ x \quad \text{if} \ x\not\in\Bbb{Q} \\ 0 \quad \text{if} \ x\in\Bbb{Q}\end{cases}$$

How do i prove this function is continous at $x=0$. I cannot apply the definition is seems since $f(x)-f(c)$ has two "forms" that depend whether $x$ is rational or not. Any hints greatly appriciated

Comment: If $x$ is small, then regardless of which form the function takes, $|f(x)-f(c)|$ is small.

Comment: @vadim123 You means when x is rational it is always smaller than $\epsilon$ so we dont care, but when x is irrational then i just use the deifnition?

Comment: $|f(x)| < |x|$ regardless of whether $x$ is rational or irrational.

Comment: @DougM Exactly my thought, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You should use sequences to prove continuity of the function at the point x = 0.

In fact, a function f defined on $\mathbb{R}$ is continous at a point x if it preserves limits of sequences, i.e., if $x_n \longrightarrow x_0$, then $f(x_n) \longrightarrow f(x_0)$.

Take a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that converges to 0. Then
$f(x_n)=0$ for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and so $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(0)=0$. Now suppose that $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$ and converges to 0. Then we have $f(x_n) = x_n \longrightarrow 0 = f(0)$.

It not so good written but the idea is this. 
Sorry for my english :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

By the defintion of $f$, $|f(x)-f(0)|\le|x-0|$ and the $\delta-\epsilon$ proof will work with $\delta=\epsilon$.